# Set up a predicate and delete a specific NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to delete a specific attribute

```
tipdescription | tip number | tipindex    

go to school   |  001       |   21

come home      |  004       |   54

lock home      |  008       |   86
```

How will I delete the whole column 'lock home'?
I have tried the following code

```
app = [[ UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

[req setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tips" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext]];
NSString *deletestatement =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"lock home"];

[req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tipdescription LIKE  %@", deletestatement]];
NSError *error;
Tips *std = [[app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error] lastObject];

[app.managedObjectContext deleteObject:std];
```

After running it I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-deleteObject: requires a
>   non-nil argument

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a predicate like the following:

```
[req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tipdescription ==  %@", deletestatement]];
```

a more clean approach is to predicate against the tip number (I suppose it's an identifier and is a `NSString`)

```
[req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tipnumber ==  %@", @"001"]];
```

Furthermore, put some condition control when you execute the fetch request:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* myContext = app.managedObjectContext;

NSArray* result = [myContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
if([result count] > 0) {

    Tips *std = (Tips*)[result objectAtIndex:0];
    [myContext deleteObject:std];
} else {

    NSLog(@"No result");
}
```

Comment: @JayKanyi What do you mean that it doesn't work? Could you explain? Have you tried both predicates? Maybe try to add some details for your model. Thanks.

Comment: @JayKanyi If my question was right you could mark it as answered. Or If found another solution, create your answer and then mark it as answered. Cheers.